# How to create a custom exposed filter in views?

Tags: webforms, views

I have to do an exposed filter that when a person write something it is going to show only the rows that have that.

The problem is that I can't do an exposed PHP Filter because there is no option to do it like the tohers that you can choose "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it".

The only way that I can get data of the webform submissions is using the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module, but I can't do an exposed PHP filter.

Is it is possible or not? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you construct field output with ViewsPHP you can try to use that field with Global: Combine fields filter.

Comment: I tryed that but It says ever: "No results" maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @nano140795 some details about what you are doing?

Comment: I created a Global: Combine fields filter and made it exposed, then In "Choose fields to combine for filtering", I chose Global: PHP (The value of this field is a string that I took from database) when I put something like "Monday" and there is a row with that in the DB, I don't get results, the views dont shows nothing.

Comment: I've just tried and don't get results too. Views shows my custom  php values in view, but filter doesn't work. So you should to implement hook_views_data in your module to describe tables values to Views.

Answer (score 0):

With Webform version 4.x you should be able to work directly with Webform submission data (as in the actual fields, not just the `metadata`) without having to use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php).

You have to set up some relationships to the field data before you can start working with it.  [Here is a tutorial](http://othermachines.com/blog/filter-form-submission-data-field-value-views-webform) that shows you how to do a similar task but the aim there is to sort on the field data and set up a contextual filter based on it.  However, I'd have to guess that if you can do that then you can almost certainly set up an exposed filter as well.